# how to get data from the 3 tables according to date wise in codeiginter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

```
public function St_statement() {

    $startdate = $this->input->post('SDate');
    $enddate = $this->input->post('EDate');
    $date = str_replace('/', '-', $startdate);
    $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
    $date2 = str_replace('/', '-', $enddate);
    $newDate2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date2));
    $data['startdate'] = $startdate;
    $data['enddate'] = $enddate;

    if ($this->input->post('all')) {
        $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT `pgroup`,`Item`, SUM(`Stock`) AS `Stock`,SUM(`quantity`) AS `quantity`,SUM(`Qty`) AS `Qty`FROM `opstock` LEFT OUTER JOIN `salesitem` ON `salesitem`.`Prdtname` = `opstock`.`Item` LEFT OUTER JOIN `itemmaster` ON `itemmaster`.`itemname` = `opstock`.`Item` LEFT OUTER JOIN `pgroup` ON `pgroup`.`pgroupid` = `itemmaster`.`catcode` LEFT OUTER JOIN `purchaseitem` ON `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` = `opstock`.`Item` WHERE  billdte >= '$newDate' AND billdte <= '$newDate2' AND billdate >= '$newDate' AND billdate <= '$newDate2' GROUP BY `Item` ORDER BY `pgroup` ASC ")->result_array();

        $data['query'] = $query1;

        $this->load->view('Inventory/St_Stmt', $data);

    }

    if ($this->input->post('selected')) {
        if ($name = $this->input->post('businessType')) {
            $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT `pgroup`,`Item`, SUM(`Stock`) AS `Stock`,SUM(`quantity`) AS `quantity`,SUM(`Qty`) AS `Qty`FROM `opstock` LEFT OUTER JOIN `salesitem` ON `salesitem`.`Prdtname` = `opstock`.`Item` LEFT OUTER JOIN `itemmaster` ON `itemmaster`.`itemname` = `opstock`.`Item` LEFT OUTER JOIN `pgroup` ON `pgroup`.`pgroupid` = `itemmaster`.`catcode` LEFT OUTER JOIN `purchaseitem` ON `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` = `opstock`.`Item` WHERE `pgroup` = '$name' AND billdte >= '$newDate' AND billdte <= '$newDate2' AND billdate >= '$newDate' AND billdate <= '$newDate2' GROUP BY `Item` ORDER BY `pgroup` ASC")->result_array();

            $data['query'] = $query1;

            $this->load->view('Inventory/St_Stmt', $data);

        }

    }
}
```

this is a controller code.....

my problem is how to get data from the four tables using date wise in codeiginter.
when i using where condition it only fetch the data if all the tables presents, otherwise it does not display the item.[image]

this picture used where condition.it shows only all three tables have same item.[image]

this picture does not used where condition but it shows all the data if it is not present or not.

please help to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move that where condition statement to "ON" it will work.

Eg.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `salesitem` ON `salesitem`.`Prdtname` = `opstock`.`Item` AND billdte >= '$newDate' AND billdte <= '$newDate2' AND billdate >= '$newDate' AND billdate <= '$newDate2'
```

If its in where , which is common for the all above conditions. That's why you are not getting any result. So remove it from where condition and move that condition to "ON" statement.